# Editing musics tag with myid3 library

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to edit musics tag with MyId3 library with this code:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    path = intent.getStringExtra("path");
    Log.d("path",path);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.song_name);
    album = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.song_album);
    artist = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
    File src = new File(path);
    MusicMetadataSet src_set = null;
    try {
        src_set = new MyID3().read(src);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ID3ReadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (src_set != null) {
        try {
            IMusicMetadata metadata = src_set.getSimplified();
            artist.setText(metadata.getArtist());
            album.setText(metadata.getAlbum());
            name.setText(metadata.getSongTitle());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but I'm getting this error and application forceclosed:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/regexp/RE
```

String path is `/storage/15D5-14F7/Musics/Music/Dream On.mp3`. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my library and Its solved. It seems android doesn't support some classes of `JAudioTagger` and `MyId3` library

Comment: which library do  you used ? can you share its link